# Hibernate Envers - select "all" changes for entity ID

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-envers

I have problem with Hibernate Envers. 
I have classes like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "REVINFO")
@RevisionEntity(MyRevisionEntityListener.class)
public class RevEntity {
    @Id
    @RevisionNumber
    @Column(name = "REV", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @RevisionTimestamp
    @Column(name = "REVTSTMP", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Date timestamp;

    @Column(name = "MODIFIED_BY", length = 100)
    private String modifiedBy;

    @Column(name = "COMMENT", length = 100)
    private String comment;
```

```
public class MyRevisionEntityListener implements RevisionListener {
    @Override
    public void newRevision(Object revisionEntity) {
        RevEntity a = (RevEntity) revisionEntity;
        a.setComment("Some value");
    }
}
```

How can i select every change for entity ID and their "REVINFO" object?

I've got something like this:

```
   List resultList = AuditReaderFactory.get(entityManager)
                .createQuery()
                .forRevisionsOfEntityWithChanges(ClientType.class, true)
                .add(AuditEntity.id().eq(entityId))
                .getResultList();
```

And it's almost work good. I received every "change" but `REVINFO` looks strange. All fields are null - and there are 1 more object `$$_hibernate_interceptor` which actually hold "information" but i cannot acces it via code (or i dont know how). See example at the image.
[image]

So my question is:
1 - How can i get `REVINFO` values ?
2 - Do i realy have to use entityManager, or can it be achived with different approach ?

Edit 2:
Correct me if i am wrong, but does forRevisionsOfEntityWithChanges works as Lazy Initialization? I mean, if i try to receive for example `modifiedBy` field i actually get my data. Debugger log make me confused.

Answer (score 0):

The call to `forRevisionsOfEntityWithChanges` returns an object array that contains:

- Entity instance
- Revision Entity
- Revision Type
- Property names that were changed.

> How can i get REVINFO values ? 2 - Do i realy have to use entityManager, or can it be achived with different approach ?

So in your code, to get the revision info attributes, you would do the following.  Note that in this code, the type of the revision-info object will depend on your configuration or if you're using a custom revision-info entity class in your deployment.  Just be sure to cast it to the proper type.

```
for (Object entry : resultList) {
  final Object[] row = (Object[]) entry;
  final TheRevisionEntityClassType revisionInfo = row[1];
  // now you can get the revision entity attributes from revisionInfo using getters
}
```

> Correct me if i am wrong, but does forRevisionsOfEntityWithChanges works as Lazy Initialization? I mean, if i try to receive for example modifiedBy field i actually get my data. Debugger log make me confused.

Depending on the query, yes Hibernate may use proxies and its important to understand that in this case, the visual representation you get in the debugger may or may not be accurate depending if the object's internal state gets initialized by the debugger window or not.